# What's the best practice for programming against a 3rd party dll?

Tags: c#, dll

At my company we had a library for functions pertaining to the CMS we use. However, each new version of the CMS, even a hotfix, would result in having to add the new dlls to the project and compile a library for that particular version. (Which was indeed as horrible as it sounds.)

At the moment the current solution is to just include the .cs files in every project, but that seems just as horrible to me. What's the best solution for dealing with 3rd party assemblies like this? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to recompile if the API hasn't changed. Is there some larger issue causing this?

Comment: As @Magus mentioned , you dont need to recompile if API doesnt change. Also while adding a reference to the 3rd party dll make sure in the project properties that you don't bound to specific version of the 3rd party dll , this way you can avoid recompiling for every version . In this case you can just deploy the updated assemblies and without recompiling you can make the application to work.

Comment: @Magus I can't find any project level option. Individual DLLs are marked SpecificVersion = false.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Bridge](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx) and [Adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx) patterns. Your situation sounds like an ideal candidate for those. Basically, you need to build a layer between the 3rd party dll and your code. This DLL will provide a consistent, non-changing interface to your code on one side, and talk to the 3rd party library on the other side. Whenever the library changes, all you need to do is to make changes in this adapter layer so that it becomes compatible with the new version, while not changing the interface that it provides to your main application. Rest of your application will keep working without problems.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is to use a façade class between your third party and code that you develop.  This way when they "make a wanted adjustment to their code" then you only have to adjust your façade, a single location in your code.  Some people call a façade a wrapper.

Now if you are using something that is a visual Control Set,  well then you just have to roll with the punches and very carefully install updates when the come out, do not just allow the developers to install at will.